# What's the best software/service for classifying fonts by height, ascender/descender, aperture, etc?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, contrast

Is there any font classification service (web page, app, book) that classifies fonts by x-height, ascender and descender lengths, stroke contrast, apertures and counters, besides the basic serif and sans-serif classifications?
Also if if the font is made for heading, body, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by *service*. [MyFonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/) has an open tagging system that gives you a good idea of how others classify a given font. It also has a nice "similar fonts" module on the right side of the page that will help you make connections.

If you'd like to know how a font of yours fits into the bigger picture, you could upload it through their [WhatTheFont tool](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/). Then see what typefaces it points you toward.

Then there's always [Typophile.com](http://typophile.com/) where you can ask the experts. You would likely get a better answer there, it would just take longer. [The Critique forum](http://typophile.com/forum/1) would probably be the most appropriate for such a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

This book can help you: http://www.letterfountain.com/. It uses an amended version of the Vox classification.